# How can I have a output if I put a variable inside the array square brackets?

Tags: arrays, c

How can I make `tipoDeProduto[categoriaPretendida]` work? If I put `tipoDeProduto[0]`it will output `C` but if `categoriaPretendida` is `0` it wont output anything, I dont understand how can I make `tipoDeProduto[categoriaPretendida]` work.

I would be highly appreciated if someone can help please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char tipoDeProduto[] = {'C', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'L'};
    char categoriaPretendida;
    
    printf("\n 0 - Cerveja\n 1 - Agua\n 2 - Sumo Natural\n 3 - Refrigerante\n 4 - Leite\n"
    );

    printf("\n Choose the pretended category: ");
    scanf("%c", &categoriaPretendida);
    
    printf(" You chose the category %c", tipoDeProduto[categoriaPretendida]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `categoriaPretendida` holds the value that represents the character/digit '0' (called ASCII value).

'0' is actually 48 in ASCII, or written in hex 0x30. You can see a [full table here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

So the trick to get the numeric value of 0, is actually to subtract the value of '0' from the input. Since '1' is next to '0' in ASCII, subtracting them will give exactly 1. Same with the rest of the digits.

Hence, to your solution, update the following line:

```
printf(" You chose the category %c", tipoDeProduto[categoriaPretendida - '0']);
```

Or more verbosely:

```
scanf("%c", &categoriaPretendida);

int categoriaValue = categoriaPretendida - '0';
    
printf(" You chose the category %c", tipoDeProduto[categoriaValue]);
```